# Understanding "It is bound to ..." message in describe-function

Tags: key-bindings, functions, menu-bar, help

If you ask for a function description, there is a line that starts:

```
It is bound to <...> <...> <...>
```

For example, for **isearch** it says:

```
It is bound to <menu-bar> <search> <isearch-forward>
```

What does it mean? Isn't it supposed to show the keybindings associated with the function?

Comment: What do you get when you do `C-h k C-s`?

Comment: I have ergoemacs enabled, so `C-s` is bound to some other function and isearch is bound to `C-f`. The message for `C-h k C-f` shows the keybinding (wrongly: it says `Alt-f` instead of `C-f`). But if I do `M-x describe-function isearch-forward` I get exactly what I typed in my question. wasamasa answer below, and @Drew comment answer my question!

Comment: This is unrelated to the question but you can do `C-h f` instead of `M-x describe-function`.

Answer (score 5):

Menu bar items are represented as keybindings internally.  So, this means that on the one hand keybinding-related actions will involve menu bar items and on the other one that clicking the "Search" item in the menu bar would yield a list where `isearch-forward` would be a valid action.

FWIW, the docs tell me something slightly different:

```
It is bound to C-s, <menu-bar> <edit> <search> <i-search> <isearch-forward>.
```

Comment: It's possible that the OP has bound `C-s` to something else.

Comment: Oh sure, I'm just a bit more worried about them having a different menu bar sequence as these shouldn't change often.

Comment: Mine says the exact same as yours. Looks like the OP probably typed it out instead of copying the text verbatim from the \*Help\* buffer.

Comment: It might help to add that the example you give shows **two** key bindings for `isearch-forward`, **separated by a comma**. The first is the key `C-s`. The second is the "key" `<menu-bar> <edit> <search> <i-search> <isearch-forward>`, which you described. The comma is maybe not obvious, and likewise for the fact that everything after the comma represents a single key binding.

Comment: ahhh, your comment (Drew) clarifies what I wanted to know!

Comment: It is bound to cause confusion! Can a function be bound and determined to a key sequence? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The example you give shows *two* key bindings for `isearch-forward`, separated by a comma.

The first is the key `C-s`. The second is the "key" `<menu-bar> <edit> <search> <i-search> <isearch-forward>`, which you described.

The comma is maybe not obvious, and likewise for the fact that everything after a comma represents a single key binding.